# How to make a manual outward phone call using AWS connect?

Tags: amazon-web-services, phone-call, amazon-connect

I am trying to use connect to make a manual outbound call from a webpage to my different customers who are meeting a certain criteria.

All the examples I see on the internet/tutorials are related to incoming calls. What will be the process?

1. Create a control flow first  with  entry point, play prompt, record call, end. Where will the exact conversation with the customer happen? Which block do I have to use?
2. Attach the control flow to the phone number (using the dashboard)
3. Where do I go on the menu to initiate the call?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I see it Amazon Connect service is to provide a fast way for building and maintaining a customer service call center. meaning that 99% of the time the customer will be the one to initiate the call.

for making an outbound calling your agents will need to use the Contact Control Panel (CCP) for answering calls and placing calls.

there are a couple of steps you will need to do before you can initiate a call.

1. enable outbound call for the Connect instance [image]
2. create an agent in the "User management" page with a "routing profile"
3. go to the setup of the "routing profile" of the agent you just created and configure the "default outbound queue". [image]
4. Create "Outbound whisper flow" - optional
5. Configure the Outbound properties in the Queue [image]
6. open another browser tab the Amazon Connect instance login URL, login with the agent details [image]
7. click on the phone symbol on the top-right corner, a new window will pop up, click on "Number pad", dial a number and make the call [image]

Comment: Terrific ! This is working Great! As a next step, if I want to have a prededined 10 phone nos to call for the Agents. It will be very nice so that Agents don't make that mistake. Is it possible ? Thanks again.

Comment: Judi, I do not fully understand your question. can you elaborate?

Comment: Let me try to elaborate. Say I have 10 customers to call. I don't want my agents to key in the phone nos. I want to automate the calling part but still want to have the agents talk to the customers. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: if the customer list is pretty small and fixed, you can use "Quick connects" (in the Amazon Connect menu under "Routing"). but if this list is dynamic and changing daily I'm not sure this will be the best approach for you.